# AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer '!stt' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

I have an Audio App that from time to time is need to encode audio data from PCM to AAC format. I'm using software decoder (Actually I don't care what encoder is used, but I've checked twice, and there's software decoder). I'm using (https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine library)

I setup Audio session category as `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord`

Have these formats

```
// Output format
outputFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
outputFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;
outputFormat.mFormatFlags = kMPEG4Object_AAC_Scalable;
outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
outputFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 0;
outputFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 0;
outputFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 0;
outputFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1024;

// Input format
audioDescription.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioDescription.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame  = 2;
audioDescription.mBytesPerPacket    = sizeof(SInt16);
audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame     = sizeof(SInt16);
audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * sizeof(SInt16);
audioDescription.mSampleRate        = 44100.0;
```

And All works perfectly with `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers` == `YES`

But when I setup `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers` with `NO` then:

```
iOS Simulator - OK
iPod (6.1.3) - OK
iPhone 4S (7.0.3) - Fail with ('!sst' error on `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer`) call
iPad 3(7.0.3) - Fail
```

As I already said all works fine until I change audio session property `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers` to `NO`

So the question is:

**What is this error about**? (I didn't found any clues in Headers and documentation what does this error mean (There's also no '!sst' string in any public framework header))

**How can I fix it**?

If you have any other Ideas that you think I need to try - Feel free to comment in.